# What is DIV style for HTML center tag?

Tags: css, html

What is DIV style for HTML center tag?

Comment: FWIW, the direct equivalent of `<center>...</center>` is `<div align="center">...</div>`. `center` is simply shorthand. However, both are deprecated in HTML 4.01. You are better off using the CSS alternatives below, which is probably what you are after judging by your tag. There is no direct 1-1 equivalent in CSS since the `center` tag centres HTML elements AND textual content. These are really two separate entities.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML:

```
<div id="something">
Content goes here.
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#something
{
  width: 850px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: There's no use of align, or text-align? That's odd.

Comment: @Mithras - Contrary to belief, that actually centers text inside the `<div>` rather than the `<div>` itself. But perhaps you want that.

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` as in my example is a little better and takes up less characters in the style sheet, when dealing with hundreds of styles or more every char helps for performance.

Comment: The `center` tag centres both elements and text within those elements, there is no direct 1-1 equivalent in CSS. @Anagio That might not be "better" if you are setting top and bottom margins elsewhere in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalent. The `<center>` tag not only centers its containing text, but any block element too. You can mimic each of those separately, but not simultaneously.

For centering any inline/inline-block content (text, images, videos etc) you would use apply the following to a div or other block element:

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

For centering a block element itself, use this:

```
.blockcenter {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Obviously replace `200px` with the desired width of the block, and `0` with whatever value you prefer for the top/bottom margins. Also note you should generally use class names that describe the element, not its presentation.

Comment: The `<center>` tag centres _everything_, not just the containing text.

Comment: @w3d yes you are correct, just tested this myself. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `margin: auto;` to center a `div`. It doesn't technically matter whether it's internal/embedded, or external.

As the comment below points out, however, this will **not** work in inline elements.

As mentioned above, `text-align: center;` would be used to center text within an element.

Comment: Inline elements _cannot_ be centred using `margin:auto`. "...internal/embedded, or external." - what do you mean by this?

Comment: You're correct, I forgot about it not working on inline elements. I'll edit that part.

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 0 auto;` will only center something in CSS if you also add a `width` specifier.  Without `width` it won't work - it will be placed on the left.  But this means it is not equivalent to the `<center>` tag, for which you did not need to specify any widths.  And *IF* you know the width of something, and have to bother to specify it in a CSS sheet, one line for each of your objects on the page (that have different widths), then you may as well just give the left margin. (software: HTML5, linux, Firefox 31)

CSS is hopeless in not centering.  (Presentation language?  Rubbish!)

Answer (score 0):

To center a div tag on your page you would use this code. If you want the text centered within the content div you then add `text-align:center;` to the #content ID style

```
​#wrapper{
    background:#444;
}
#content{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:whitesmoke;
}​

​<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">test</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
    {
        position:absolute;
    }
```

you will need to delete it before the margin styles take effect.